# Jquery and Bootstrap intergration

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to find how to make the active class be added in onloading the page. For some reason it doesn't work here is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark navbar-custom fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-left" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" /></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#products">Products</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About Us</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Jquery file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = window.location;
    $('ul.nav a[href="'+ url +'"]').parent().addClass('active');
    $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url;
    }).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

One small detail is on the home page I have section tags, but they do have their own respective pages. /products /aboutus etc

Comment: If you `console.log` the `url`, what's the result?

Comment: you supposed to do `var url = window.location.href`?

Comment: Actually gives an error before it excutes saying:  $ is not defined
    at onLoad.js:1. Just standard scripttag:     <script src="vendor/jquery/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: the jquery is not included correctly.

Comment: Import jQuery from a CDN

Comment: output was: Location {replace: ƒ, assign: ƒ, href: "http://localhost:63342/url.com/index.html", ancestorOrigins: DOMStringList, origin: "http://localhost:63342", …}

Comment: `window.location` is object. that has `href` and `$('ul.nav a[href="'+ url +'"]').parent().addClass('active');` does not work

Comment: I tried what you said and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var activePage = url;
    $('.nav-item a').each(function () {
        var linkPage = this.href;

        if (activePage == linkPage) {
            $(this).closest("li").addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```